# How to query a model made up of multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm doing the CS50 Web programming course, learning to use Django. The learning exercise basically has you recreating [this](http://www.pinocchiospizza.net/menu.html) pizza restaurant menu with django.

I've created some models for the data, and now I'm trying to use Django templating to create a menu page for the pizzas.

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models

class intToppings(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    intToppings = models.IntegerField() # 0 Cheese, 1/2/3, 5 Special

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.size}"

class PizzaBase(models.Model):
    base = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.base}"

class Toppings(models.Model):
    topping = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.topping}"

class Pizza(models.Model):
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # CASCADE will delete all Regular Pizzas if their size is deleted (as opposed to .SET_NULL)
    base = models.ForeignKey(PizzaBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    intToppings = models.ForeignKey(intToppings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField() # price in cents

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.size} {self.base} {self.intToppings} Pizza"
```

There's an entry `"small"` and `"large"` in the `Size` db, and for `intToppings` there is one entry with name `"cheese"` and an int of `0`, another for `"1 topping"` with an int of `1`, etc.

And for the `Pizza` model, I made an entry for every combo on the menu, ie:

```
<QuerySet [<Pizza: small Regular Cheese Pizza>, <Pizza: small Regular 1 Topping Pizza>, <Pizza: small Regular 2 Toppings Pizza>,  ...
... <Pizza: large Sicilian 2 Toppings Pizza>, <Pizza: large Sicilian 3 Toppings Pizza>, <Pizza: large Sicilian Special Pizza>]>
```

On my views.py, I can't really pass that whole data set to the django template because it's not sensible/possible to loop through it to create an html table. (my html table is identical to the one on [their website](http://www.pinocchiospizza.net/menu.html), one table for regular pizza, one for sicilian.)

I'm trying to solve this issue by first constructing a list/array or dict object that will pass data to the django template in a structure that is easy to loop through. And to do this I want to query the `Pizza` model.

Essentially, all I'm looking to do is (pseudo code: `SELECT Pizza WHERE size="small" base="Regular", intToppings=0` and get the price for that pizza.
I don't seem to be able to query the foreign keys though;

```
Pizza.objects.all().filter(price=1220)
```

works but isn't what I need. What I need is;

```
p = Pizza.objects.all().filter(base="Regular", size="small", intToppings=0)
print(p.price)
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) about lookups that span relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the field names of the related models? Like this:

```
p = Pizza.objects.filter(
    base__base="Regular",
    size__size="small",
    intToppings__intToppings=0)
print(p)
```

Like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) say,
you first access the related model (say `base`) and then you access the field of that related model (`__base`) and compare that to the string you want, resulting in  `base__base='something'`.

Maybe you even could rename the field `PizzaBase.base` to `PizzaBase.name` to make it less confusing.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly, except the last one I had to do `intToppings__intToppings=0`. And yes I agree, with that syntax, definitely best to rename them to `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p = Pizza.objects.filter(
    base__base = "Regular",
    size__size = "small",
    intToppings_id = 0, 
)
```

**Note** that I changed `intToppings` to `intToppings_id`.  If you need to filter by a foreign key, you can pass in the `intToppings` object, or you can add `_id` to the end of the column name and simply insert the pk value.